# tf strided_slice equivalent in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to "backport", in a sense, the tensorflow strided slice operation tf.strided_slice (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice) into numpy, but I can't figure out how to do it. More specifically, given the arguments for a call to strided slice, how would I manipulate these into array indices to produce the same result that a call to tf.strided_slice would produce?

(I know that tf.strided_slice is for use on tensors and numpy slice indexing is for use on numpy arrays)

Comment: Based on a quick glance at the docs, I suspect it will be easier to translate a specific example, rather than a general one.  It says that `strided_slice` is the low-level function, while indexing in the `numpy` style is the high level one.  That is, the `tf` `getitem` translates the indexing tuple into a `strided_slice` call.

Comment: You're going to want to create a list of [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) objects conforming to your keywords.  You'll probably need `np.unpackbits` as well for the boolean inputs.  Don't have time to write it all out but that should get you started.